# Access Denied when executing through cygwin openssh

Tags: ssh, permissions, cygwin

When I execute the command "iisreset" through an ssh terminal on a remote windows machine, I get the following error:

```
Attempting stop...
Restart attempt failed.
Access denied, you must be an administrator of the remote computer to use this
command. Either have your account added to the administrator local group of
the remote computer or to the domain administrator global group.
```

When I type whoami, it shows that I am the administrator. My cygwin ssh session is running as the "cyg_server" user who has admin privileges.
My ssh server is configured with privilege separation and allows me to login as administrator.
When I run the command locally, it works fine. The problem is execution through ssh.
I've also used process monitor to see what's going on, but it does not indicate the problem.

That is pretty strange because I am able to do admin-only operations in remote ssh such as:

```
echo "hi">/cygdrive/c/x.txt
rm /cygdrive/c/x.txt
```

Turning off UAC did not make a difference.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem: unable to start/stop services using net start/net stop from a remote password-less (public/private key) SSH user.  Attempting to start/stop the service was resulting in a "System Error 5 has occurred.  Access is denied." error).

I had to install Cygwin's LSA authentication package (see http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-setuid-overview) in order for (I presume) setuid to work properly for password-less logins.

The problem should go away once LSA is installed on the Cygwin/SSH host and the machine has been rebooted.

Comment: Using pwd auth over SSH (ugh) would also work per this old thread: https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2003-07/msg01026.html.  I'm excited to try the LSA package though, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I got scared of the LSA package mentioned in @user3609241's answer because of this sentence in the LSA docs:

> as soon as the LSA encounters serious problems (for instance, one of
>   the protected LSA processes died), it **triggers a system reboot**.

But, those same docs point to a very easy way to "runas" SYSTEM - just use the `at` command:

```
$ date
Mon, Jan 12, 2015  8:17:35 PM

$ at 20:18 iisreset
Added a new job with job ID = 1

$ at
Status ID   Day                     Time          Command Line
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                1   Today                   8:18 PM       iisreset
```

It works, at the cost of having to wait up to 59 seconds.

(wrapping the above sequence of commands in a simple-to-call script is left as an exercise to the reader; our management util is written in Perl so it was pretty straightforward).

Answer (score 0):

Run the Cygwin terminal as administrator